# Chrome causes disk to thrash

Tags: google-chrome

I am having two problems with Google Chrome:

- There are a ridiculous number of "chrome.exe" processes running. For example, right now I only have one tab open and there are ten chrome.exe processes.
- Whenever I have a few Chrome tabs open, my disk starts thrashing like crazy.

This does not happen with Firefox.

What might be causing this and how can I fix it?

I'm running Win 7 Pro (64 bit). Google Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m. I have 4G RAM.

Answer (score 3):

> There are a ridiculous number of "chrome.exe" processes running. For example, right now I only have one tab open and there are ten chrome.exe processes.

Chrome uses a [multi-process](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture) [model](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models) to increase security and stability. This means that it runs each tab, plugin, and extension in a separate process. It is not uncommon to have several instances of `chrome.exe` running.

You can determine exactly what they are hosting by pressing <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the Chrome Task Manager.

If you still have several processes running even without any extensions or plugins, then you may have zombie processes from a previous session that crashed or didn’t close correctly. You can find out for sure by closing Chrome and seeing if any remain behind in the Windows Task Manager.

> I have 4G RAM. Whenever I have a few Chrome tabs open, my disk starts thrashing like crazy. This does not happen with Firefox.

Chrome has a [tendency to use a *lot* of memory](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome%20memory). The multi-process model causes some additional memory overhead, but today’s web-pages just use a lot of memory with all the Flash, JavaScript, images, social-network plugins, ads, and so on.

Even with 4GB of RAM, it is easy to run out of physical memory while having to many high-density–content tabs open. When that happens, it resorts to using [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Memory) and starts [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging). When it does this, it has to transfer unused memory to the disk so that it can free up physical memory, which of course means a lot of disk activity.

> how can I fix it?

There’s a few things you can do:

- Get more RAM
- Open fewer tabs (and keep an eye on the memory usage)
- Get a faster hard-drive or replace it with an SSD
- Uninstall any extensions and plugins that you don’t need
- Disable any extensions and plugins that you don’t use all the time
- Either turn off JavaScript and/or images globally and then set exceptions for some sites, or leave them on globally and turn them off for some sites
- Set plugins to Click-to-Play so that they are not all automatically run

  [image: Screenshot of Chrome plugins set to click-to-play]

Comment: Or, you can upgrade to [CoolNovo](http://coolnovo.com/), which features the ability to change the process model from the default process-per-site-instance model to a process-per-tab or single-process model. (no affiliation)

Comment: @gparyani, that’s what Chrome used to use, but they changed it to a per-tab model a while back. Even so, the multi-process overhead isn’t *that* much, maybe a couple of megabytes per process.